# Do I need a visa to transit through South Korea?

Tags: visas, transit, airports, south-korea, vietnamese-citizens

I am a Vietnamese citizen. I am planning to buy a round-trip flight ticket from Taipei to Los Angeles (America) and I will transit in Seoul airport.

Do I need a visa if I want to enter Seoul (not over 72 hours)?

My first route is TPE-ICN-LAX, do I need a visa if I stay one night in Seoul?
My second route is LAX-ICN-TPE, do I need a visa if I stay one night in Seoul?

Of course, I have a valid US visa, and onward ticket that I booked.

Comment: Thank for your answers. Do i need to apply any documents before my trip ? Or i just pass the immigration on the day of arrival in Seoul? Thanks,

Comment: You just show your onward e-ticket to immigration and answer their questions, if they ask any. To make it quicker, when approaching the officer have the passport open **at the US visa page**

Answer (score 6):

From http://www.immigration.go.kr/HP/IMM80/imm_04/imm_p01/vm2.jsp:

> ## Visa-free Entry for tour and transit
>
> Nationals of the countries below can enter Korea without a Korean visa for a stay of up to 30 days, if their purpose of visit is tour or transit
>
> ### Asia
>
> MACAO, BRUNEI, SAUDI ARABIA, U.A.E, YEMEN, OMAN, JAPAN, QATAR, TAIWAN, H.K(90days), KUWAIT
>   ※ Only Diplomatic·Official passport : INDONESIA, LEBANON
>
> ### North America
>
> U.S.A, CANADA(6months)
>
> ### South America
>
> GUYANA, GUATEMALA, VENEZUELA, ARGENTINA, ECUADOR, HONDURAS, URUGUAY, PARAGUAY
>
> ### Europe
>
> MONACO, Vatican, BOSNIA HERCEGOVINA, Cyprus, SAN MARINO, Serbia & Montenegro, SLOVENIA(90days), ANDORRA, ALBANIA, CROATIA
>
> ### Oceania
>
> GUAM, NAURU, NEW CALEDONIA New Caledonia, MICRONESIA, SAMOA, SOLOMON IS, KIRIBATI, FIJI, AUSTRALIA(90days), MARSHALL IS, PALAU
>
> ### Africa
>
> SOUTH AFRICA, Mauritius, Seychelles, SWAZILAND, EGYPT

(Note that Vietnam is not on the list.)

> Visitors meeting the following requirements also can enter Korea without a Korean visa for a stay of up to 30 days, if their purpose of visit is transit
>
> Note) Nationals of Cuba,Macedonia ,however, must apply for korean visa, even if they meet these requirements
>
> - Holding a visa or a re-entry permit of the U.S. Japan, Canada, Australia, or New Zealand (5 countries)
> - Travelling from either of the five countries to a third country via Korea, or travelling from a third country to either of the five countries via Korea
> - Holding a confirmed onward flight ticket for departure within 30 days
> - No Immigration offence records, while in the five countries
>
> Those who have visited Korea more than 4 times in recent two years, or those who have visited Korea more than 10 times in total can enter Korea without a Korean visa, notwithstanding the requirements above
>
> Note) However, this facility for frequent visitors is not applicable to nationals of "China (P.R.C)", "Cuba" , "Macedonia"

It appears that you are eligible for transit without visa if you have no past immigration offences in any of the five countries.

Comment: I am curious how an airline agent would be able to verify whether someone has visited Korea "more than 10 times in total" for the purpose of deciding whether to allow someone without a visa.

Comment: @ZachLipton perhaps if the traveler brings the old passports to show the entry stamps, the airline agent could look at those.  Timatic says simply "Visa required, except for Passengers who have previously
entered Korea (Rep.) at least 4 times within the last 2 years or at least 10 visits in total."

Comment: It's a strange list you quote -- especially the Europe part which omits many of the countries that have visa-free access to South Korea [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea). Ordinarily one would think a government website more reliable, but it really sounds hard to believe they would give visa-free access to Albanians and San Marinese, but _not_ to either Italians, French, Gernmans or Brits. Did they have a falling-out with the EU or what?

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's because EU citizens (other than Cypriot and Portuguese) can enter under a separate, better Regime (for 90 days to be exact). I agree, the Website is very poorly constructed

Comment: @Crazydre but the existence of a list of countries with more permissive terms means that the absence of Vietnam from this list doesn't imply that Vietnamese need visas. Unfortunately I probably won't have time to fix this answer over the weekend.

Comment: @phoog Well, the list os obviously outdated anyway, because it lists Serbia and Montenegro as a single country. Citizens of today's Serbia can visit visa-free for 90 days, and Japanese visas are no longer accepted for this form of "transit"

Answer (score 6):

Airline agents go by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=VN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=KR&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), which states:

> Passengers **with a visa issued by** Australia, Canada, New Zealand or **USA** to nationals of any country except for China (People's Rep.), Cuba, Iran, Macedonia (FYROM), Sudan and Syria, only if in transit through Korea (Rep.): -holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within 30 days; when arriving from a third country, departing to the country that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-YVR); or arriving on a direct flight from the country that issued the visa (a visa that expired on departure from that country is accepted), departing to a third country (e.g. YVR-ICN-DEL).

In other words: **yes**, you can enter Seoul and spend one night there. However, print this site to show the Airline agent just in case

Comment: i wonder why Timatic does NOT mention Japan. I feel the need for realtime sync and transparency via some kind of easy-to-use global tool accessible to the public on the internet.

Comment: @computingfreak Because they've stopped accepting Japanese visas. Asked the Timatic Team to double check with their Korean sources

Answer (score 1):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=PH&DE=CN&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=KR&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting Seoul Incheon (ICN), for a max. transit For details time of 24 hours.

So as long as your transit is under 24 hours and you're transiting through Seoul you don't need a visa regardless of your nationality or destination.

Comment: This would work if staying in the transit area.  Not sure about this since OP wants to stay in a hotel.