# Need a visa to transit through South Korea?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, indian-citizens, seoul

Reference to this question:
[Do I need a visa to transit through South Korea?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79838/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-south-korea?newreg=9de5f14fd14340e0b06b5e8380f7bc23)
It is not clear that can I spend my time outside the airport?
I'm Indian national with valid passport till 2024, valid US visa (business B1) and have ticket back from USA to India. I'll transit in Incheon for close to 20 hours. So this my return trip from USA to India.

Am I allowed to transit without visa ? Am i allowed to go outside the airport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes you can!**

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=kr&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of India with a visa
>   issued by [...] **USA** [...] if holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within 30 days; when [...] arriving from the country that issued the visa (a visa that
>     expired on departure from that country is accepted) and
>     departing to a third Country.

Comment: https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client_post.cgi

Comment: Transit Without Visa (TWOV): Passing through an international
transit area of the airport in order to board a connecting (or

to proceed by the same) flight, without entering the country
(i.e. clearing immigration).  Thanks @crazydre but it still not clear whther i can leave the airport or not.   Also "Leaving the tour group is
not permitted. "

Comment: @Pushpa There are different types of transit. If **not** leaving the Airport, you can Transit without a visa for 24 hours regardless of any visas you have. Then there is a tour Transit program for max 72 hours which lets you leave the Airport, again regardless of what visas you have. Finally, there's this 30-day Provision for those having visas from (for example) the US, like you do, permitting you to Exit the Airport and stay for max 30 days. So it's three different rules, which are **not** related

Comment: Thank you very much :) I got scared about spending 20hrs and now i'm  okay. Cheers :)